# How to read csv file typed in non english language in python

Tags: python, pandas

I can read the CSV file information using the English Language.

But I can't able to read CSV file information written in Non-English Language.

This is the code which I can read all the information if it is present in English Language but can't read in other language. Why?

```
import pandas as pd
asd=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Mypc\Desktop\merge.csv')
print(asd)
```

Comment: please Add your sample csv data.

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. Could you provide an example of what you got and what you expected?

Comment: I am using the language as Tamil and get the error as UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: @DishinHGoyani  My sample csv "எல்லாம் நல்லது.",0 
"மிகவும் அருமை.",0

Comment: @DishinHGoyani Mu column names are Data and Label

Comment: Read the file by changing the encoding to utf-16. Thanks Bobby

Comment: import pandas as pd
asd=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Mypc\Desktop\love.csv',encoding='utf-16')
print(asd)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Answer (score 2):

Read the file by changing the encoding to utf-16

```
    import pandas as pd
asd=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Mypc\Desktop\love.csv',encoding='utf-16')
print(asd)
```